# How to draw shapes in html and css with a circle inside a square?

Tags: html, css

I want to create this shape with HTML and CSS.

[image: this is the image]

Comment: Frankly that design is probably too complex for CSS. I'd suggest using SVG instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One gradient and one mask can do it:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  display:inline-flex;
  background:conic-gradient(#f5f6fa 90deg,#2b4170 0 180deg,#8292a2 0 270deg,#d5503d 0);
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  margin:auto;
  background:inherit;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(50% 50%,#fff 98%,#0000) -75px -75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works or give some links where I can learn this wizardry? Thanks

Comment: @TJ I don't really have a link to share besides the documentation of conic gradient or mask (that you can easily find on MDN) but probably a step by step can help you better understand: https://jsfiddle.net/pjnwkbf0/